# A better method for naming properties which are elements in a 3D array?

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array, naming-conventions, readability

I have "Ball"s, with some properties like "x", "y" and "z", which loop over a number of "Steps".

I am doing a lot math where the properties interact, so, to make my code easier to read and write, I have named the positions of the elements of the array as what they physically are:

```
x = 0
y = 1
z = 2
```

With that in place, I can write like this:

```
for Step in xrange(steps):
    for Ball in xrange(balls)
        ball[Ball,**z**,Step] + ball[Ball,**velocity_z**,Step]*dt
```

As opposed to remembering the position of every property:

```
for Step in xrange(steps):
    for Ball in xrange(balls)
        ball[Ball,**2**,Step] + ball[Ball,**2**,Step]*dt
```

This is my current list of properties:

```
x = 0
y = 1
z = 2    
vel_x = 3
vel_y = 4
vel_z = 5
acc_x = 6
acc_y = 7
acc_z = 8
mass = 9
radius = 10
w_x = 11
w_y = 12
w_z = 13
mag_w = 14
mag_vel = 15
mag_acc = 16
velh_x = 17
velh_y = 18
velh_z = 19
```

This then determines the second dimension of my array to have size 20. I love how this makes the code easy to read and write, and I certainly don't want to use dictionaries or anything extremely inefficient like that, as my program needs to run as fast as python can run, but I am wondering if anyone has a more elegant solution that is as computationally fast.

Thank you.

Comment: using constants is elegant enough. Please respect [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) in your code

Comment: The slow part of your code is going to be the looping over all balls and all steps. If you need speed, consider using numpy arrays or pandas DataFrames. DataFrames will additionally allow you to work with labeled arrays, which seems to be what you're trying to accomplish here. But the approach you've taken could largely be supplanted by a namedtuple, I believe.

Comment: maybe check out dask (http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/). it supports labeled layers and strives to be efficient. it's built by astro-nerds so I'm sure it has computation in mind.

Comment: I will look at dask. Thanks. @Pynchia what am I not respecting?

Comment: @jme I AM using numpy arrays. ball[Ball,x,Step] is a numpy 3D array.

Comment: @Michael Of course, I should have realized when I saw the indexing. In that case you might look into Python's new `enum` module to make defining the constants cleaner.

Comment: @jme. Thank you. I will.

Comment: If anyone else reads this, The suggestions given don't really apply, they I appreciate the suggestions, and they may be useful to someone else. Dask is for processing data that has already been produced, and enum is more cumbersome than the setup I have made, and very likely less efficient.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that setting constants for the element positions in my numpy arrays is a good solution for intuitive code reading and writing.